# Renumber a value based on what's not already assigned to a grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query where when a value (Loan Number) is greater than 1000 then I want to give that value a different (lower) number. This data would be grouped by person.

I cannot reuse a Loan Number that already exists for that person. The lowest value in the "over 1000" list should have the lowest available Loan Number for that person; the next lowest value would get the next lowest available Loan Number, and so on.

I cannot renumber the entire list, the existing Loan Numbers less than 1000 have to stay the same.

| EMPLOYEE | LOAN NUMBER | DESIRED NEW LOAN NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123000 | 1 |  |
| 123000 | 3 |  |
| 123000 | 5 |  |
| 123000 | 8000 | 2 |
| 123000 | 8500 | 4 |
| 123000 | 9000 | 6 |
| 456000 | 1 |  |
| 456000 | 5 |  |
| 456000 | 7 |  |
| 456000 | 8000 | 2 |
| 456000 | 8500 | 3 |
| 456000 | 9000 | 4 |
| 456000 | 9500 | 6 |

Here is a query with the data from above:

```
CREATE TABLE #EmployeeLoanNumbers
(
EMPLOYEE BIGINT
,LOANNUMBER BIGINT
)

INSERT INTO #EmployeeLoanNumbers (EMPLOYEE,LOANNUMBER)
VALUES
('123000','1'),
('123000','3'),
('123000','5'),
('123000','8000'),
('123000','8500'),
('123000','9000'),
('456000','1'),
('456000','5'),
('456000','7'),
('456000','8000'),
('456000','8500'),
('456000','9000'),
('456000','9500')

SELECT * FROM #EmployeeLoanNumbers
```

I have tried `ROW_NUMBER()`, but all I can find it that it wants to renumber all of them, and I cannot figure out a way to exclude the numbers that are already in use.

Comment: which daravase system are you using i am guessing sql server?

Comment: SSMS isn't a DBMS it's an IDE(like) application, @JenGJ . *SQL Server* is the RDBMS.

Comment: Filling in gaps like that is actually quite tricky, and usually not useful - especially in a database context. Consider, what do you actually gain by having the gaps filled in? Does it really affect anything important?

Comment: Yes, this is important to the business. I do not have a choice in the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better way, but unless you're working at Fanny Mae, perhaps this solution will perform well enough:

```sql
SELECT  *
,   CAST(NULL AS INT) AS [LOAN NUMBER NEW]
INTO #data
FROM    (
    VALUES  (123000, 1, NULL)
    ,   (123000, 3, NULL)
    ,   (123000, 5, NULL)
    ,   (123000, 8000, 2)
    ,   (123000, 8500, 4)
    ,   (123000, 9000, 6)
    ,   (456000, 1, NULL)
    ,   (456000, 5, NULL)
    ,   (456000, 7, NULL)
    ,   (456000, 8000, 2)
    ,   (456000, 8500, 3)
    ,   (456000, 9000, 4)
    ,   (456000, 9500, 6)
) t (EMPLOYEE,[LOAN NUMBER],[DESIRED NEW LOAN NUMBER])


;WITH loanNumbers AS (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) AS row
    FROM    (
        VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)
    ) v(v1)
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)
    ) v2(v2)
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)
    ) v3(v3)
)
, employees as (
    SELECT  DISTINCT EMPLOYEE
    FROM    #data
)
, changeNumbers AS (
    SELECT  *
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE ORDER BY [LOAN NUMBER]) AS sortOrder
    FROM    #data d
    WHERE   [LOAN NUMBER] >= 1000
)
UPDATE  t
SET [LOAN NUMBER NEW] = x.newLoan
FROM    changenumbers t
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE ORDER BY row) AS sort
        ,   ln.row AS newLoan
        ,   o.EMPLOYEE
        FROM    employees o
        CROSS JOIN LoanNumbers ln
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS(
                SELECT  1
                FROM    #data d
                WHERE   d.EMPLOYEE = o.EMPLOYEE
                AND d.[LOAN NUMBER] = ln.row
            )
    ) x
    ON  x.sort = t.sortOrder
    ANd x.employee =t.EMPLOYEE
```

The basic idea is to create a pseudo table of numbers from 1-1000 (`loanNumbers`) which in combination with distinct `Employees` will generate all the available gaps in existing data. Then one numerate these gaps by ROW_NUMBER and JOIN them against the loan table rows (`changenumbers`) which are similarily numerated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, this looks like it'll work the way I want! I appreciate the time you took to help me.